# Changing x value's scale in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am undergoing my university dissertation and need to create some dive shape profiles for Yellowfin tuna. i have created the graph but am having issues with the scale of my X axis, as it is a time value and i have a 6 panel plot. My time-frame is in 5 minute intervals, adding up to 15 mins per graph. The time frames for my graph are as follows: (a)15-minute timespan 11:45AM-12 PM 20/1/2019. (b) 15-minute timespan 16:47-17:02PM 26/1/2019. (c) 15-minute timespan 16:40-16:55 8/2/2019. (d) 15-minute timespan 17:10-17:25 14/2/2019. (e) 15-minute timespan 16:15-16:30 26/2/2019. (f) 15-minute timespan 16:40-16:55 9/3/2019. Note that the dates do not matter necessarily, but would be an extra bonus to attach to my graph. Fixing the scale to 500m in depth would be fantastic also. Each of these panels, are a separate excel spreadsheet.

[image]

[image]

Comment: My guess is that your x values are categorical (strings) instead of something number-like. There are plenty of questions on SO having to do with fixing axis issues like this, but we can't help without at least a sample of data.

Comment: I see. i could paste an excel screenshot but i cannot link the document. the only columns that were used were depth and time. i will post a screenshot of my excel spreadsheet

Comment: No, pictures of data are not much better, I'm not going to spend time transcribing what you have easily available. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info for several good discussions on how to make a question **reproducible**, especially hints about using `dput` and `read.table`

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unclear of what you're trying to do without more of an example but if you're trying to change the axis but look into ggplot scale_x_discrete()

Comment: Answers really need to demonstrate working code, and whenever possible with some form of data and demonstrated execution. While the OP has provided nothing to work with, if you think that `ggplot2::scale_x_discrete` can resolve the issue, then I suggest you work with a public dataset and *demonstrate* what you think is going on and how to remedy it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).